# logo image appearing in print for firefox but not appearing for chrome and microsoft edge

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I am trying to have a link which on click does windows print function on a particular html element that includes a logo.
The logo appears if I try the link in firefox browser but the logo is not appearing with chrome and microsoft edge.
When if I do a `window.print()` on the whole document body the image is appearing with all 3 browsers.

Can help me point to the right direction to solve the issue with print with logo in chrome and edge for the element.

**TestPage.jsp**

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/anti_csrf.tld" prefix="anti_csrf" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <title><spring:message code="Common.Info1.ApplicationName" text="Common.Info1.ApplicationName"/></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/main.css"/>"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/spinner.css"/>"/>
 
</head>

<body>
    <div>Some Text</div>
    <div>Some Text</div>
    <div>Some Text</div>
    <div><select class="form-control" id="yy" name="yy" onChange="actionRefresh()">
         <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="21" step="1">    
           <option value="i" selected>${i+1}</option>
         </c:forEach> 
      </select>
    </div>
   <div class="row form-element-margin">
<div class="col-sm-11"> </div>
<div class="col-sm-1">                                                  
   <a href="#" onclick="printDiv('generateData')"><i class="fa fa-print fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
    <div  style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 10pt;" id="genericData">
       <div style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 10pt;" class="row form-element-margin">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 txt_right">
<c:if test="${not empty requestScope.logo}">
<label class="header"><img  height="35" src="<c:url value="/resources/assets/${requestScope.logo}" />"/></label>
</c:if> 
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">    </div>
<div class="col-sm-4 text-center">  
<label  class="header" ><b><c:out value="${requestScope.ReportTitle1}" /></b></label></br>
<label class="header"><b><c:out value="${requestScope.ReportTitle2}" /></b></label>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>Some more text</div>

<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/Testmenu.js" />"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Testmenu.js**

```
function printDiv(divName) {
var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

Comment: What do "_windows print function on a particular html element_" and "_window.print() on the whole document body_" mean? `window.print` prints the focused `window`, and it doesn't take parameters.

Comment: @Teemu, I am trying to replace the document.body.innerHTML first with the document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML and then doing a window.print() on it.

Comment: Ah okay ... That's an awful way to prepare a page for printing, thought, as it will most often break the original page for the screen. Please check how to use  [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries) instead.